# Can't select TinyMCE HTML elements

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, tinymce

Please check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/pe47bj86/) JSFiddle.

The `<div id="wp-post_content-editor-container" ..>` on **line 1** and `<textarea class="wp-editor-area input-text-area" ..></textarea>` on **line 108** are the only HTML element I can select (with `document.querySelector()` or `document.getElementById()`). The rest give me `null` .

Why is that? And how can I get the HTML element from TinyMCE?

My goal is to set an event listener in an element inside the `<iframe>` tag on line 8.

**UPDATE:**

I use this command to select the HTML element:

```
let divContentEditor = document.querySelector('#wp-post_content-editor-container');
let divMceu7 = document.querySelector('#mceu_7');
            
console.log('prints the html element');
console.log(divContentEditor);
console.log(divMceu7);
```

As you can see I print the result on the console, but here is what I got:

[image]

When I select the  `<div id="mceu_7" ..>` it's give me `null`.

My goal is actually to get the element `body[id="tinymce"] > p` inside the `<iframe>` tag. You can see it on `jsFiddle` that I attached **on line 97**. And then put an event listener for word counters.

```
const inputTextArea = document.querySelector('body[id="tinymce"] > p');
const wordCount = document.getElementById("word-counter"); // I put this element right below the tinyMCE text area
if (textArea && wordCount) {
    inputTextArea.addEventListener('input', () => {
        const txt = inputTextArea.value.trim();
        wordCount.textContent = txt.split(/\s+/).filter((item) => item).length;
    });
}
```

But since I can't even select the `#mceu_7`, I can't select the element deeper than that. It gives me `null`.

Comment: @Ruvee I use a freelance engine that builds with WordPress. Those HTML are auto-generated. So I guess it is about how the engine generates the HTML, isn't it? I don't have any idea what should I show to make my questions clear. So what you would like to see more about the code to help you answer my question?

Comment: @Ruvee I edited the Jsfiddle to add the HTML doc inside the <iframe>. Apparently it doesn't get copied when I copy the whole HTML

Comment: @Ruvee I updated the questions, please kindly check them